# SQL LIKE not properly returning

Tags: php, sql

```
$vendor=$this->db->query("SELECT code from `sources` where uniquevendor=1");
foreach( $vendor->result() as $vendor_data ) {

    $data['queryItem']=$this->db->query("SELECT sourcing, `item_sku`, sum(quantity)as total  FROM `item` WHERE   `item_sku` like '$vendor_data->code%' AND quantity<0  group by `item_sku` order by total asc;");
}
```

`$venodor` has 18 vendor .But in the  `$data['queryItem']`  Like Operator is working for only the last vendor name and return value only for last one . Why this happening ??

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `$data['queryItem']` in each iteration?

Comment: How can I keep every value ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: why not use join ? ` item_sku = code`

Comment: @jonm - Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Problem not solved yet

Comment: Hi @jonm Just do one thing in your code add $data['queryItem']['vendorid']. This will return all vendor items in array.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping to your current structure I assume you need something like this:

```
$vendor=$this->db->query("SELECT code from `sources` where uniquevendor=1");
foreach( $vendor->result() as $vendor_data ) {
    $data[$vendor_data->code]=$this->db->query("SELECT sourcing, `item_sku`, sum(quantity)as total  FROM `item` WHERE   `item_sku` like '$vendor_data->code%' AND quantity<0  group by `item_sku` order by total asc;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try

```
select b.sourcing, b.item_sku, sum(b.quantity)as total from sources a left join item on a.code = b.item_sku
```

I don't know why you not using join.